# Не могу написать условия для meta_query

Tags: php, wordpress

Нужна помощь с такой задачей, есть кастомный тип, у которого есть acf поле (галерея) в котором находятся фото и видео, хочу сделать фильтр, чтобы при активном чекбоксе отображались только те записи в которых есть видео:

```
public static function registerFilterFunction(): void
    {
        $checkboxValue = isset($_POST['checkbox']) ? $_POST['checkbox'] : '';
        $checkboxVideoValue = isset($_POST['phone_has_video']) ? $_POST['phone_has_video'] : '';
        $paged = isset($_POST['paged']) ? intval($_POST['paged']) : 1;

        $args = [
            'post_type' => 'phones',
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'posts_per_page' => 12,
            'paged' => $paged,
            'suppress_filters' => true,
        ];

        $meta_query = [
            'relation' => 'AND'
        ];

        if ($checkboxVideoValue === 'checked') {
            $meta_query[] = [
                'key' => 'phones',
                'value' => '',
                'post_mime_type' => 'video',
                'compare' => '=',
            ];
        }

        if ($checkboxValue === 'checked') {
            $meta_query[] = [
                'key' => 'phone_new',
                'value' => '1',
                'compare' => '='
            ];
        }

        $args['meta_query'] = $meta_query;

        $query = new WP_Query($args);

        if ($query->have_posts()) {
            while ($query->have_posts()) {
                $query->the_post()

                get_template_part('template-parts/phones-grid');
            }
            wp_reset_postdata();
        } else {

        }
        die();
    }
```

Comment: Не совсем понятно что это за мета ключи `'phone_new'` и `'phones'` и какое отношение они имеют к галерее. ACF галерея хранит данные в виде сериализованного массива. И Вы не можете использовать `post_mime_type` в `meta_query`, где Вы [тут такой параметр нашли](https://wp-kama.ru/function/wp_query#meta_query)?

Comment: А зачем die() в конце? Чтобы страницу грохнуть?

Comment: @ВикторКарев есть такая необходимость при аякс запросах в WordPress. Но лучше всего использовать `wp_die();`